# Not invalid type of index when creating non-clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I have this table `Test`:

```
ID - int primary key not null, 
CODE - nvarchar(max), 
NAME - nvarchar(max)
```

It has clustered index on `ID`.

But in an execution plan, the search uses `ID` and `CODE` columns.

How can I add non-clustered index to the table? When I try, I get an error:

> Column code in table Test is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index

Could you recommend what actions must be done?

I need to add the index for the query fast processing.

There is already clustered index which is not effective in query processing.

In SSMS, for creating NON-CLUSTERED INDEX - the only option was to add `ID` as key column and then to add CODE as `Include` in the index. But it means that table will have both CLUSTERED INDEX on ID column and NON-CLUSTERED INDEX on ID with CODE include. Is that right?

What is the best practice:

- If table can have both clustered and non-clustered indexes basing on same id key column?
- How should you do for fixing the problem?

Comment: You can't index `MAX` columns, they are too large as you are stating the value is likely to be between 8,000 and 2 billion bytes in size; so you are stating here that the name is likely over 4,000 characters.

Comment: Seems highly unlikely that the `CODE` column would need to be `MAX`. Is there a specific reason for this - or has it been created automatically via an ORM with no length specified? If not make it a sensible length and create a non-clustered index on it.

Comment: `CODE` column was created automatically as result of software installation when building the ER diagram. So, I cannot change the column length.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but you can use `INCLUDE`

As Lamu points out, such a NON Clustered Index would **not** be used, as every search that includes ID, would use the clustered Primary KEY, to get its wated rows and ignore the code.

The PRIMARY KEY means that the every row has a UNIQUE ID.

```
CREATE TABLe test_table (
ID  int primary key not null, 
CODE  nvarchar(max), 
NAME  nvarchar(max)
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_NC_test_table_CODE ON test_table(ID) INCLUDE(CODE)
```

Comment: This index is redundant, the Primary Key is already the clustered index, this is just the same index as the clustered one, but non-clustered. The clustered index includes all the columns already so this index would never get used.

Comment: Thank i forgot , to mention that in my answer

Comment: So, does it mean that if the column already has clustered index on `ID` column, it will ignore the non-clustered index and extra other columns added with `INCLUDE` key. What if the search in app will be by 3 columns as `ID`, `CODE` and `NAME`. If the optimizer will build the effective plan? Or in my case, it will be more useful, to delete the existing clustered key and create another one (as composite) clustered key with 3 columns in it?

Comment: SQL Server processes the query and look which is the (almost)best index, as teh clustered  unique index on Id will be the fastest, there is no need to add a non clustered with 'ID and as we know all non clustered indexes  save internally the row-id to find the row faster, so the non-clusered wit ID is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can't index MAX columns, they are too large as you are stating the value is likely to be between 8,000 and 2 billion bytes in size; so you are stating here that the name is likely over 4,000 characters.

Seems highly unlikely that the CODE column would need to be MAX. Is there a specific reason for this - or has it been created automatically via an ORM with no length specified? If not make it a sensible length and create a non-clustered index on it.